# Table valued function parameter as varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have this table-valued function in my SQL Server 2008 database:

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.fct1(@Code varchar(10) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
   select CODE , NOM 
   from CODIF 
   where NUMERO = 'TP'
   and CODE =  @Code 
)
```

When I call it from my code :

```
 sSQL = "select * from fct1(" & Code & ")"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sSQL, Connection)
        If Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then Connection.Open()
        Dim rd As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

I get this error :

> column name not valid : 'EA2'

I need to know :

- What is the reason of this error?
- How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missed `'`

```
sSQL = "select * from fct1('" & Code & "')"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sSQL, Connection)
        If Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then Connection.Open()
        Dim rd As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the `'` from the sql.

You should probably parameterise the SQL and try to use using as well:

```
using conn as new sqlconnection(connstring), comm as new sqlcommand("",conn)

    conn.open()

    comm.commandtype = commandtype.text
    comm.commandtext = "select * from fct1(@Code)"
    comm.parameters.addwithvalue("@Code",Code)

    Dim rd as sqldatareader = comm.executedatareader

end using
```